# Unresponsive MySQL database

Tags: mysql, rackspace

I've setup a MySQL server on Ubuntu machine.

When running a heavy query (the table has over 1M rows), the database becomes unresponsive.

Upon connection it returns:

*Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip address' (110)*

To make it responsive again, I need to kill the process of the heavy query (visible under "show processlist").

Is there a way of preventing this? I used to host the same database on Rackspace MySQL server. Even though it had the same amount of memory, it was more efficient and it never became unresponsive even when running similar queries.

Comment: Do *not* use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: I think your question should go at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: +1 for dba, they will solve it in few seconds :)